# Use PKRevealController (Slide Menu) on existing project

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

**Before anything and everything, I know there exists a similar thread by another user, I tried the code answered in that but it didnt worked for me as my VCs and storyboard is a bit different, thus asking same question with my setup and parameters**

My storyboard and app looks like this, my initial rootViewController as a tabBarController.

[image: Storyboard]

I am using this PKRevealController to add a slider left menu bar
https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController/blob/master/Documentation/USAGE.md

I added the following code (taken from the answer on similar question I found on SO) to my appDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
PKRevealController *revealController = (PKRevealController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *leftViewController = [[GDmenuViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *frontViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarCtrl"];
    [revealController setLeftViewController:leftViewController];
    [revealController setFrontViewController:frontViewController];
```

GDmenuViewController is the UITableViewController class I made for my UITableView menu to use on left
tabBarCtrl is the StoryBoardID for the tabBarController I set

Upon compilation I am getting the following error

```
2014-03-16 18:18:06.659[3595:70b] -[UITabBarController setLeftViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcf565a0
2014-03-16 18:18:06.662[3595:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setLeftViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcf565a0'
```

--------Update-------------

I changed the code in app delegate to the following since my tabBarController was my initialVC

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    GDmenuViewController *leftViewController = [tabBarController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftMenu"];
    PKRevealController *revealController = [PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:tabBarController leftViewController:leftViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```

Now I am not getting that error but still my menuViewController (TableView) isnt showing up.
I can run the app and even slide to see that the PKVC is working but instead of my tableView, it just shows up a gray blank View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who comes up across similar problem, here is how I fixed and made it to work :

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    GDmenuViewController *leftViewController = [tabBarController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftMenu"];
    PKRevealController *revealController = [PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:tabBarController rightViewController:leftViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```

my TabBarController is my rootViewController as well as the entry point
my leftMenu is the swipe menu TableViewController with a custom class GDmenuViewController

PS: If the swipe works but you dont see your swiped menuVC as expected (grey in my case), check every thing in identityInspector of your menuVC, most probably problem will be there.
In my case, my cells (static) were buggy, so I had to delete all cells and readd them.